# Create a Zip File from a string of jpeg URLs separated by commas (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, foreach, zip

I have a cell in google sheets that is connected to a frontend UI. My users can upload images from the frontend, and the images show up in google sheets as a string of urls like the below example:

https://img_1.jpeg, https://img_2.jpeg, https://img_2.jpeg

I want to use the Google Apps Script Zip Utilities to zip those images up. Then I want the link to the zip file to be input in an adjacent column.

Here is the link to the google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-S9bQy1EW2lB_Q7SXl-2TAcnYYmisUmBdwT5cixuQ8U/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried a few different ways to make this happen, and so far I'm only successful getting ONE url link to process. I think I need to use forEach, but I'm not sure how to make it work.

**Here are some of the scripts I've tried:**

This one works. It creates a zip file in google drive, then I can use a different script to put the zip file into the google sheet. BUT it only works if there is just one url.

```
function myZip2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var images = "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2022/11/29/science/00tb-cats1/00tb-cats1-videoSixteenByNineJumbo1600.jpg";

  // Fetch the image files and get the Blob data
  var imagesBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(images).getBlob();

  // zip now references a blob containing an archive of the images
  var zip = Utilities.zip([imagesBlob], "POP.zip");

  var zipFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1nqvhUowWQ1JVQvHbjIYy84mXjSHASBBk');
  zipFolder.createFile(zip);

}
```

In the next one one, I'm trying to create a new folder in google drive, add all the image urls to it, then just zip the whole folder. But the last image in the string fails every time. AND I didn't figure out how to zip the folder.

```
function createPOPFolder() {
  concatURLs()

  // to try: first create folder, then upload images, then zip entire folder
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1nqvhUowWQ1JVQvHbjIYy84mXjSHASBBk');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var campaign = sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow()).getValue();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder("POP | " + campaign +"");
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).setValue("POP | " + campaign +"");

  var formulas = sheet.getRange(2,4, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var string = formulas.toString();
  var urls = string.split(", ");

  urls.forEach(url => {
    console.log(url)
    const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
    newFolder.createFile(blob)
  })
  }
```

And this last one is a script I pulled from stack overflow. I was hopeful, but I still get an error.

```
function isImageToImage(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const formulas = sheet.getRange(2,2, sheet.getLastRow()-1).getFormulas().flat();
  const urls = formulas.map(formula => {
    return /\"(.*?)\"/gmi.exec(formula)[1]
  })

  
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1nqvhUowWQ1JVQvHbjIYy84mXjSHASBBk')

  urls.forEach(url => {
    console.log(url)
    const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
    folder.createFile(blob)
  })

}
```

Here's the error I get:

[TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyqK6.png)

Lol please help!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your question, it seems that you tried various scripts. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I poked around your spreadsheet/script, and you may have already figured this out, but in case you still need help, just want to confirm what you are trying to do. You want to take a string of image urls, fetch the images, store the fetched images in a zipped folder on drive, and add a link to the zipped folder to the spreadsheet is that right?

Comment: @MiguelRiveraRios that is exactly right. I actually came up with some code that works. BUT the last image always fails. So the new folder gets created, and all the images populate except the last one. Lol and nothing gets zipped yet. I updated the second block of code in my original message to show what is sort of working.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize I usually try to at least modify your existing code to help you come up with a solution, but it was a little difficult for me to figure out what was the working code across your post and the sample sheet you shared, so I just wrote up some new code based on your requirements (although I believe it should look familiar based on what you were working on and maybe you can use this to see what was causing your issue).

The main function here is `zipImagesInDrive` and I believe it gets at what you need. You can fiddle with the range in `getImageUrls` if the string of concatenated image urls is in a different location. Similarly, you can change the range in `updateSpreadsheet` if you want the final url somewhere else.

```
function getImageUrls() {
  const imageUrlsStringRange = 'E2';
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const imageUrlsString = sheet.getRange(imageUrlsStringRange).getValue();
  

  return imageUrlsString.split(',').map((imageUrl) => imageUrl.trim());
}

function getImage(imageUrl) {
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(imageUrl).getBlob();
}

function updateSpreadsheet(zipId) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  sheet.getRange('E3').setValue(zipId);
}

function zipImagesInDrive() {
  const imageUrls = getImageUrls();
  const imageBlobs = [];

  for (const imageUrl of imageUrls) {
    const imageBlob = getImage(imageUrl);

    imageBlobs.push(imageBlob);
  }

  const zip = Utilities.zip(imageBlobs, 'ZippedImages.zip');
  const zipId = DriveApp.createFile(zip).getUrl(); // this places the zip file in your drive root folder
  // const zipId = DriveApp.getFolderById('<<FOLDER_ID>>').createFile(zip).getUrl(); // if you want to put the zip folder in a specific place use this

  updateSpreadsheet(zipId);
}
```